# Attribute for only allow anonymous in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, unauthorized

I know that there is an attribute when a user must be authorize or not. You can also place `[AllowAnonymous]` above it. See also code below:

```
[Authorize] // only when the user is authorize
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous] // also when the user in not authorize.
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "")
    { /* Some code */ }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    { /* Some code */ }
}
```

But is there also an attribute for **allow anonymous only**. For example: a login page only show when the user is **not authorize**?

Comment: There isn't one. And there is a reason there isn't one.

Comment: @MarkHomer: and can you tell me why there isn't one?

Comment: why would you ever went to prevent authorized users? it just screams bad design

Comment: @MarkHomer: a login page only show when the user is not authorize. I find it normal that an authorized user can't go the the login page. Not that there is a button or link for the authorized users but if they do it by the url...

Comment: so in your Controller check user logged in and if so Redirect to another action.

Comment: @MarkHomer: yes, for the login and register action. Is it so strange maybe?

Comment: I wasn't asking a question lol. In your CONTROLLER check user is authenticated and REDIRECT to another ACTION you do not need decorator as I said in first place there is not one for a reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's an existing one, but there's no reason you can't roll your own. However, I would point out that it seems odd that you'd go to the extra effort to restrict content to an authenticated user:

```
public class AnonymousOnly : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
             // Do what you want to do here, e.g. show a 404 or redirect
        }
    }
}
```

Then just decorate your class/method with this new attribute:

```
[AnonymousOnly]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "")
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: Yes it is odd to restrict content to an authenticated user, but I will not that an authenticated your can go to the login and register page. When he is authenticated, you can't go to the login page to authenticate again...

Comment: @Hein if it's for these two cases, I'd just check if they were already logged in within the method and `RedirectToAction` rather than create a new class for one method. That being said, it's all down to preference so approach it however you and your team would prefer.